# Value of rip pushed to kernel stack during an interrupt

Tags: interrupt

this is a very simple question but I couldn't find an answer for it.

When an interrupt is raised, let's say a synchronous interrupt (for example because I divided by 0), the value of `rip` that is pushed to the kernel stack will be matching the previous instruction (division by 0), or the next instruction?

I would expect it to point to the next instruction but I read somewhere that it would still point to the same instruction.

Does anyone know the answer?